# Make a sidebar from react-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidebar

I am trying to create a Bootstrap sidebar like this picture here.

[image: sidebar]

I have looked at all the code on react-bootstrap and Twitter Bootstrap and I am yet to find a how-to code this. Basically, if they are viewing on a desktop, I want the sidebar to be visible, otherwise hidden.

The sidebar should stay still while the content on the page scrolls up and down.

Comment: Are you asking how to create this sidebar while using bootstrap? Or are you asking how to make it, regardless of whether we use bootstrap or not? The sidebar can be easily made without bootstrap.

Comment: @AskYous needed to be bootstrap as that is the system we are using - see my answer below.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ok so for people who want to make a sidebar sadly the news is you gotta make it all yourself.

What I have done is the following.

1. See the example at https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar
2. Create sidebar.js somewhere in your app.

> ```
> import React from "react";
> import {Nav} from "react-bootstrap";
> import { withRouter } from "react-router";
> import '../pages/style/Dashboard.css'
>
> const Side = props => {
>    
>
>     return (
>         <>
>     
>             <Nav className="col-md-12 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar"
>             activeKey="/home"
>             onSelect={selectedKey => alert(`selected ${selectedKey}`)}
>             >
>                 <div className="sidebar-sticky"></div>
>             <Nav.Item>
>                 <Nav.Link href="/home">Active</Nav.Link>
>             </Nav.Item>
>             <Nav.Item>
>                 <Nav.Link eventKey="link-1">Link</Nav.Link>
>             </Nav.Item>
>             <Nav.Item>
>                 <Nav.Link eventKey="link-2">Link</Nav.Link>
>             </Nav.Item>
>             <Nav.Item>
>                 <Nav.Link eventKey="disabled" disabled>
>                 Disabled
>                 </Nav.Link>
>             </Nav.Item>
>             </Nav>
>           
>         </>
>         );
>   };
>   const Sidebar = withRouter(Side);
>   export default Sidebar
> ```

3. My Dashboard.css has the following in it.

> ```
>  .sidebar {
>         position: fixed;
>         top: 0;
>         bottom: 0;
>         left: 0;
>         min-height: 100vh !important;
>         z-index: 100;
>         padding: 48px 0 0;
>         box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
>     }
>     #sidebar-wrapper{
>         min-height: 100vh !important;
>         width: 100vw;
>         margin-left: -1rem;
>         -webkit-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
>         -moz-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
>         -o-transition: margin .25s ease-out;
>         transition: margin .25s ease-out;
>     }
>     #sidebar-wrapper .sidebar-heading {
>         padding: 0.875rem 1.25rem;
>         font-size: 1.2rem;
>     }
>     
>     #page-content-wrapper {
>         min-width: 0;
>         width: 100%;
>     }
> ```

Then final step
In the file you want it to be show in do the following

```
import React from "react";
import {Container, Row, Col, Card, Form, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
import Sidebar from "../moduls/sidebar.js";
import './style/Dashboard.css'

const Dash = props => {
   

    return (
        <>
         <Container fluid>
                <Row>
                    <Col xs={2} id="sidebar-wrapper">      
                      <Sidebar />
                    </Col>
                    <Col  xs={10} id="page-content-wrapper">
                        this is a test
                    </Col> 
                </Row>

            </Container>
        </>
        );
  };
  const Dashboard = withRouter(Dash);
  export default Dashboard
```

Comment: is there any way to add dropdown

Comment: Isn't work because sidenav width doesn't allow click other elements

Comment: its no longer true , check here : https://github.com/ivp-dev/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu

Comment: @Nanda try this: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

Answer (score 3):

As of 2022 there is pure react-boostrap based component called `react-boostrap-sidebar-menu` .  It is the cleanest solution so far and quite customizable.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu

https://github.com/ivp-dev/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu

```
import SidebarMenu from 'react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu';

<SidebarMenu>
  <SidebarMenu.Header>
    <SidebarMenu.Brand>
      {/* Your brand icon */}
    </SidebarMenu.Brand>
    <SidebarMenu.Toggle />
  </SidebarMenu.Header>
  <SidebarMenu.Body>
    <SidebarMenu.Nav>
      <SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
          {/* Menu item icon */}
        </SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
          {/* Menu item title */}
        </SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
      </SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
    <SidebarMenu.Nav/>
    <SidebarMenu.Sub>
      <SidebarMenu.Sub.Toggle>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon />
        <SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
          {/* Submenu title */}
        </SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
      </SidebarMenu.Sub.Toggle>
      <SidebarMenu.Sub.Collapse>
        <SidebarMenu.Nav>
          <SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
            <SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
              {/* Submenu item icon */}
            </SidebarMenu.Nav.Icon>
            <SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
              {/* Submenu item title */}
            </SidebarMenu.Nav.Title>
          </SidebarMenu.Nav.Link>
        </SidebarMenu.Nav>
      </SidebarMenu.Sub.Collapse>
    </SidebarMenu.Sub>
  <SidebarMenu.Body/>
</SidebarMenu>
```

Comment: is there page where i can see a menu implemented using this library? in the demo page I can't see the react code that uses this library. @phyo arkar Lwin

Comment: The demopage is the one that use it. 
Don't be afraid to dive  into the source code. : https://github.com/ivp-dev/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu/blob/main/www/src/pages/app.tsx

Comment: Library is broken and lacks documentation. Don't waste any time on in like I did

Comment: @NecipAllef Lib works fine, if ~270 repo use it. Maybe its better to check your code. Please, share your example we can find a solution. Best regards

Comment: I don't have the code right now, but let's just say it works for your case and some others and that's it. Honestly, any library that lacks documentation is not worth using because it shows the lack of faith by the owner. If you choose to use it, good luck @Vadim

Comment: @NecipAllef It difficult to find the lib covers all cases. But the lib has documentation (https://ivp-dev.github.io/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu) and working example with source code. If you have any issue just ask. But I think you need something easy to use without any affort from your side, in this case good luck.

Comment: Who is going to click on a link called "Demo" and expect to see documentation? No wonder the library has just a handful of stars. By the way, I remember spending a couple of hours trying to accomplish a task with this library and failing. I am not looking for an effortless solution, I am just telling other people to not waste time on this library as I did. Best, regards, later @Vadim

Comment: @NecipAllef No wonder you failed if you even din't check the demo. Do you always suggest others do not waste time on things you failed with?

Comment: I only suggest others to not waste time on things when it is nothing but a waste of time. I don't know why you think I didn't check the demo. I don't know why you still insist on arguing with me. You can't change my mind or my comment. The library sucks, sorry. @Vadim

Comment: @NecipAllef If you can't set up styles from bootstrap to make it works your opinion is as useless as your suggestion

Comment: Here is an example of this lib - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-sidebar-menu-ck23cz

Comment: Caused countless errors when using with Vite.js and React 18 in early 2024. Fixing one error was followed by three new errors.

Answer (score 2):

of course, you have to make the navbar yourself and the examples above are very valid, but cdbreact speeds up the process a lot faster. just add cdbreact using

npm I cdbreact

or

yarn add cdbreact

and then import CDBSidebar, CDBSidebarContent, CDBSidebarHeader, etc. with cdbreact, you don't need to bother about installing bootsrap in your react app.
cdbreact also comes with icons, and a lot more.

import React from 'react'
import {CDBSidebar,
CDBSidebarContent,
CDBSidebarHeader,
CDBSidebarFooter, CDBSidebarMenu,
CDBSidebarMenuItem} from 'cdbreact';
import {NavLink, Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {} from 'react-router-dom';

```
const Sidebar=()=>{
    return (
        <div style={{display:'flex', height:'100%', overflow:'scroll initial'}}>
            <CDBSidebar textColer="#fff" backgroundColor="rgb(37, 90, 122)">
                <CDBSidebarHeader prefix={<i className="fa fa-bars fa-large"></i>}>
                    <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
                </CDBSidebarHeader>
                <CDBSidebarContent className="sidebar-content">
                    <CDBSidebarMenu>
                        <NavLink exact to="/dashboard" activeClassName="activeClicked">
                            <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="columns">
                                Transfer
                            </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink exact to="/dashboard" activeClassName="activeClicked">
                            <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="columns">
                                Transfer
                            </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink exact to="/dashboard" activeClassName="activeClicked">
                            <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="columns">
                                Transfer
                            </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
                        </NavLink>
                        <NavLink exact to="/dashboard" activeClassName="activeClicked">
                             <CDBSidebarMenuItem icon="columns">
                                Transfer
                            </CDBSidebarMenuItem>
                        </NavLink>
                    </CDBSidebarMenu>
                </CDBSidebarContent>
                <CDBSidebarFooter style={{textAlign:'center'}}>
                    <div className="sidebar-btn-wrapper" style={{ padding :'20px 5px' }}>
                        sidebar footer
                    </div>
                </CDBSidebarFooter>
            </CDBSidebar>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

you can also follow the guide here https://dev.to/devwares/how-to-create-a-responsive-sidebar-in-react-using-bootstrap-and-contrast-5gi2 follow this link to see

Comment: For the life of me, I haven't been able to use cdbreact despite it being installed. Seems it's not an issue with the package itself.

Comment: can you share what your challenge is? error message or something

Comment: Last update in Github: 5 months ago. 
Is this project alive or dead?
I tried to install but got errors on installation.

Comment: what is the errors? you can either use mdbreact or cdbreact. they are similarly the same. what is your error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

One can now use a library, `react-bootstrap-drawer`, which provides a sidenav / drawer which was taken directly from the `react-bootstrap` documentation. Oddly, this is not a component provided by the library itself so one must use a third-party library:

```js
import 'react-bootstrap-drawer/lib/style.css';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    Col,
    Collapse,
    Container,
    Row,
} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Drawer, } from 'react-bootstrap-drawer';

const ApplicationDrawer = (props) => {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleToggle = () => setOpen(!open);

    return (
        <Drawer { ...props }>
            <Drawer.Toggle onClick={ handleToggle } />

            <Collapse in={ open }>
                <Drawer.Overflow>
                    <Drawer.ToC>
                        <Drawer.Header href="/">Application</Drawer.Header>

                        <Drawer.Nav>
                            <Drawer.Item href="/settings">Settings</Drawer.Item>
                        </Drawer.Nav>
                    </Drawer.ToC>
                </Drawer.Overflow>
            </Collapse>
        </Drawer>
    );
};

const Application = (props) => {
    return (
        <Container fluid>
            <Row className="flex-xl-nowrap">
                <Col as={ ApplicationDrawer } xs={ 12 } md={ 3 } lg={ 2 } />
                <Col xs={ 12 } md={ 9 } lg={ 10 }>{ props.children }</Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

See: https://github.com/SimpleSigner/react-bootstrap-drawer

Answer (score 1):

One can do it using pure react-bootstrap. The trick is to **use collapse for the the dropdown** and **use composition**

**SideBar**

```
const SideBar = ({children}) => {
  return <Nav className={'flex-column'}>{children}</Nav>
}

SideBar.Dropdown = SideBarDropdown
SideBar.Item = SideBarItem

export default SideBar
```

**SideBarDropdown (note the collapse)**

```
const SideBarDropdown = ({title, children}) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Container fluid className={'p-0 m-0'}>
      <Nav.Item onClick={() => setOpen(!open)} className={'p-0 m-0'}>
          {/*Your Dropdown Text*/}
      </Nav.Item>
      <Collapse in={open}>
        <div> {children} </div>
      </Collapse>
    </Container>
  )
}
export default SideBarDropdown
```

**SideBarItem**

```
const SideBarItem = ({title, value, onClick}) => {
  return (
    <Container fluid className={'p-0 m-0'}>
      <Nav.Item onClick={onClick} className={'p-0 m-0'}>
          {/*Your Dropdown Text*/}
      </Nav.Item>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default SideBarItem
```

**Sample Use Case**

```
const ToolsSidebar = ({ setCurrentTool, currentTool }: SideNavProps) => {
  return (
    <SideBar>
      <SideBar.Dropdown title={'Datasets'}>
        <SideBar.Item title={'Files'} value={'some_files'} />
        <SideBar.Item title={'Documents'} value={'something_else'} />
      </SideBar.Dropdown>
      <SideBar.Dropdown title={'Title1'}>
        <SideBar.Item title={'Creator'} value={'some_writer'} />
        <SideBar.Item title={'Components List'} value={'some_list'} />
      </SideBar.Dropdown>
    </SideBar>
  )
}
export default ToolsSidebar
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain the reasoning behind `SideBar.Dropdown = SideBarDropdown` and `SideBar.Item = SideBarItem`?

Comment: It's just for using dot notation.